# Ajax requests getting appended on multiple hits

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

In case the user fills some invalid data, an ajax request is fired and error message is displayed. Now when the user again corrects the data/or enters invalid data again, 2 requests are fired, the next time 3 and it keeps on adding up.

**This is probably because of the parsley js library. If I remove parsley code it works fine.** Any idea?

Here is the ajax code

```
    $('#upload-profile-button').on('click', function(e) {
        $("#upload-profile-form").parsley().validate();
        $("#upload-profile-form").parsley().on('form:validate', function (formInstance) {
            var isFormValid = formInstance.isValid();
            if(isFormValid){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#upload-profile-button').html('Uploading...');
        var fd = new FormData($("#upload-profile-form")[0]);
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : '/mbatch/batch/uploadBatch',
            data : fd,
            processData : false,
            contentType : false,
            beforeSend : function() {

            },
            success : function(response) {
                if (response.data.fetchTpodSuccess == true) {
                    window.location.href= "/mbatch/batch/listBatch";
                } else {
                    new PNotify({
                        title: 'Notice',
                        text: response.message,
                        type: 'error',
                        styling: 'bootstrap3'
                    });
                        $('#upload-profile-button').html('Submit');
                }
            },
            error : function(data) {
                new PNotify({
                    title: 'Notice',
                    text: JSON.parse(data.responseText).message,
                    type: 'error',
                    styling: 'bootstrap3'
                });
                    $('#upload-profile-button').html('Submit');
            }
        });
}
             });
   });
```

Here is the HTML code snippet

```
    <button id="upload-profile-button" type="button"
                                    class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

Any leads would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using $(document).ready(function(){ //ajax call }); surrounding your Jquery code?

Comment: Yes, it is surrounded by $(document).ready(function(){});

Comment: I have tested an equivalent sample and it's working fine, i guess your PNotify is wrong, try commenting it on "error" and see if it's working fine. Could you provide more code? TIP: you can use the "complete:" element of $.ajax to do $('#upload-profile-button').html('Submit'); (it's called after error o success :))

Comment: try posting other section of your code.Be precise. This section seems fine.

Comment: The whole js code is surrounded by $(document).ready(function(){}); function

And there are 8-9 such handlers for different click handling. All of them directly written inside ready handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out the solution.
This was because I was using data-parsley-validate in the form tag as well
and in the js as well

```
    <form id="upload-profile-form" data-parsley-validate enctype="multipart/form-data"
                        name = "uploadBatchForm"
                        class="form-horizontal form-label-left"
                        >
```

**Parsley looks at all data-parsley-validate occurrences in DOM on document load and automatically binds them if valid.
Once a form or field instance is bound by Parsley, doing $('#form').parsley(options); will update the existing options but not replace them.**

Source - http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you render your script after each call, so it could append your click function to the click event multiple times.
If this is the case, first try to unbind your click event before appending one like this:

```
$('#upload-profile-button').unbind('click').on('click',...
```